# A class trial is held with $15$ participants. When decided, all $15$ participants vote “guilty”, “not guilty”, or “abstain”.

Tags: combinatorics

A class trial is held with $15$ participants. When decided, all $15$ participants vote “guilty”, “not
guilty”, or “abstain”. When at least half of the votes are guilty, or when this cannot happen,
the voting stops. What is the number of possible trials?

I'm guessing that the voting happens sequentially. Which means, if the first person already voted guilty, the voting already stops. I've been having trouble counting the number of trials because I cannot seem to find a systematic way to determine which person can vote guilty and not stop the voting process.

Comment: I think the rules of stopping are: The vote count is sequential and stops when there are $8$ guilty votes, or when $8$ guilty votes can't be achieved by continuing the vote count.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the case since the answer is $2,228,225$, which is pretty big.

Answer (score 3):

I interpret the rules as:

  The vote count is sequential and stops when there are 8 guilty votes, or when 8 guilty votes can't be achieved by continuing the vote count.

With that interpretation, we can count the number of distinct vote count sequences as follows . . .

Let $a,b$ be the number of guilty votes and other votes, respectively, when the vote count stops.

Then either $a=8$ or $b=8$.

Let $x$ be the number of trials which end when $a=8$, and let $y$ be the number of trials which end when $b=8$.

Then we have
\begin{align*}
x&=\sum_{b=0}^7{\small{\binom{b+7}{b}}}2^b=580865\\[4pt]
y&=\sum_{a=0}^7{\small{\binom{a+7}{a}}}2^8=1647360\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence the total number of possible trials (distinguished by distinct vote count sequences) is
$$x+y=580865+1647360=2228225$$